# Convert binary data to 2’s complement and then place in output array

Tags: c#, binary, decimal, arrays

Scenario:

I have binary data. My requirement is that I need an output array of bytes contain in following order:

- Sequentially read each 2 bytes
- and then convert into 2’s complement
- and then placed into output array.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you provide *more* info? What do you mean, e.g. *I have binary data*? Do you have an array? Stream?

Comment: [`BitConverter.ToInt16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) will do almost the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing, that the *binary data* in the question is in fact an *array*:

```
  Byte[] binaryData = new Byte[] {
    0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15
  };

  Byte[] result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, binaryData.Length / 2)
    .Select(index => unchecked(BitConverter.ToInt16(binaryData, index * 2)))
    //.Select(item => (Int16) unchecked((item << 8) | (item >> 8))) // if you want to swap the endians
    .Select(value => (Int16) unchecked(~value + 1))
    .SelectMany(value => unchecked(new Byte[] {(Byte) (value >> 8), (Byte) (value & 0xFF)}))
    .ToArray();

  // Test
  // "ec, ee, ea, ec"
  // ("ed, ed, eb, eb" when endians are swapped)
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result.Select(item => item.ToString("x2"))));
```

**Edit**: in case (see comments) that each *byte* (not *2-byte word*) should be changed:

```
Byte[] binaryData = new Byte[] {
   224, 46
};

Byte[] result = binaryData
  .Select(b => unchecked((Byte) (~b + 1)))
  .ToArray();

// "20 D2"
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result.Select(item => item.ToString("x2"))));
```

Comment: @@Dmitry , I want to back assign them into binarydata(byte array).

Comment: @Nidhi Tiwari: then add appropriate `.SelectMany`. See my edit

Comment: Getting overflow exception "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Comment: @Nidhi Tiwari: two more `unchecked` required.

Comment: I have a long binary data . the solution only works for first index[0] and index[4]. index[8] but not working for index[2] why??

Comment: The Zero Index value is 224 and index[1] value is 46 in byte array. it converts the 224 to 32 but converting the 46 value to 209 which is wrong. the correct value should be 18.

Comment: @Nidhi Tiwari: you want *2-complement* from *2-bytes* (i.e. short) or from *each byte*? Short `224 46` == `E02E` (or `2EE0` depending on endian) and 2 comp is `~E02E + 1 == 1FD1` or `~2EE0 + 1 == D120`

Comment: My program gives the output ~2EE0 + 1 == D120 can you please help me to prodcue the output ~E02E + 1 == 1FD1.

Comment: //.Select(item => (Int16) unchecked((item << 8) | (item >> 8))) // if you want to swap the endians it gives the error of Getting overflow exception "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96062/discussion-between-nidhi-tiwari-and-dmitry-bychenko).